# Front-panel headphones are detected, but not working

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, alsa

When I plug headphones into the front-panel jack, `pavucontrol` detects them as such (`Output Devices > USB Audio Analog Stereo > Port: Headphones (plugged in)` when present, vs `Port: Digital Output (S/PDIF)` when unplugged). If audio is directed to this sink, `pactl` shows audio as playing (the usual output-level meter lighting up), but no sound actually comes out of the headphones. I have confirmed that the headphones work elsewhere, both in other devices and in the Line Out port on the same computer (which is unfortunately not positioned in such a way as to be usable for headphones).

The output for `pactl list cards` for the relevant card (which seems to be all motherboard built-in audio both front and back) is as follows when the headphones are plugged in:

```
Card #2
    Name: alsa_card.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 8
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "3"
        alsa.card_name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.long_card_name = "Generic USB Audio at usb-0000:00:14.0-9, high speed"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:9:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-9/1-9:1.0/sound/card3"
        udev.id = "usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "0414"
        device.vendor.name = "Giga-Byte Technology Co., Ltd"
        device.product.id = "a010"
        device.product.name = "USB Audio"
        device.serial = "Generic_USB_Audio"
        device.string = "3"
        device.description = "USB Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
    Profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 65, available: no)
        input:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 55, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6565, available: no)
        output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Stereo Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6555, available: yes)
        output:analog-surround-21: Analog Surround 2.1 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1300, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 2.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1365, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-21+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 2.1 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1355, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-40: Analog Surround 4.0 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1200, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1265, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-40+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 4.0 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1255, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-41: Analog Surround 4.1 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1300, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 4.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1365, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-41+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 4.1 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1355, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-50: Analog Surround 5.0 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1200, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.0 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1265, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-50+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 5.0 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1255, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-51: Analog Surround 5.1 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1300, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 5.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1365, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-51+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 5.1 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1355, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-71: Analog Surround 7.1 Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 1200, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo: Analog Surround 7.1 Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1265, available: no)
        output:analog-surround-71+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Surround 7.1 Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 1255, available: no)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5500, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5565, available: no)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo Duplex (IEC958) (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5555, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo
    Ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        analog-input-linein: Line In (type: Line, priority: 8100, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Part of profile(s): input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo
        iec958-stereo-input: Digital Input (S/PDIF) (type: SPDIF, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Part of profile(s): input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (type: Speaker, priority: 10000, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-21, output:analog-surround-21+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-21+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-40, output:analog-surround-40+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-40+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-41, output:analog-surround-41+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-41+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-50, output:analog-surround-50+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-50+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-51, output:analog-surround-51+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-51+input:iec958-stereo, output:analog-surround-71, output:analog-surround-71+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-surround-71+input:iec958-stereo
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (type: SPDIF, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Part of profile(s): output:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:analog-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:iec958-stereo
```

With the headphones unplugged, the following is the diff from the above:

```
26c26
<       output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: yes)
---
>       output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: no)
28c28
<       output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Stereo Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6555, available: yes)
---
>       output:analog-stereo+input:iec958-stereo: Analog Stereo Output + Digital Stereo (IEC958) Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6555, available: no)
51c51
<   Active Profile: output:analog-stereo
---
>   Active Profile: output:iec958-stereo
65c65
<       analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
---
>       analog-output-headphones: Headphones (type: Headphones, priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
```

(Card #0 is a GPU with HDMI out, card #1 is a webcam with mic)

I am on Arch Linux. I have already checked `alsamixer`; nothing is muted there on any card.